# How to get user's role discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do a info command as you can see but in the roles section, i can't display the user's roles.
At first i did a working command but it display the "@everyone" role too, so i did a string for remove it (`mention.remove("everyone")`) but it doesn't work it gives an this error:

```
Command raised an exception: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I tried to replace "everyone" with "@everyone" too but it still doesn't work..

```
@client.command()
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):

    mention = []
    for role in user.roles:
        mention.append(role.mention)
        mention.remove("everyone")

    b = ", ".join(mention)


    embed = discord.Embed(title="Info:", description=f"Info of: {user.mention}", color=discord.Color.orange())
    embed.add_field(name="Top role:", value=user.top_role)
    embed.add_field(name="Roles:", value=b)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: use `print(mention)` to see what you have on list - for sure there is no `"everyone"` nor `"@everyone"`. I don't understand why you expect `everyone` on this list. And why you try to remove it in every loop, You should use `if "everyone" in mention` before remove. OR better `if role.mention != "everyone"` before you append.

Comment: i can't see the traceback beacuse i have an error handler so, i'll delete it for now and i'll send you the full error @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an `if` statement to check if the name of the role is `@everyone`.

```
@client.command()
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):

    mention = []
    for role in user.roles:
        if role.name != "@everyone":
            mention.append(role.mention)

    b = ", ".join(mention)


    embed = discord.Embed(title="Info:", description=f"Info of: {user.mention}", color=discord.Color.orange())
    embed.add_field(name="Top role:", value=user.top_role)
    embed.add_field(name="Roles:", value=b)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use `if` to check value before you add to list - and then you don't need `remove`

```
mention = []

for role in user.roles:
    if role.mention != "@everyone":
        mention.append(role.mention)
```

The same as list comprehension

```
mention = [role.mention for role in user.roles if role.mention != "@everyone"]
```

---

**BTW:** if you want to remove something then do it only once after `for`-loop and also use `if` to check if element exists

```
mention = []

for role in user.roles:
    mention.append(role.mention)


if "@everyone" in mention:
    mention.remove("@everyone")
```

Comment: The bot now send "@@everyone" so i added `if role.mention != "@everyone" or role.mention != "@@everyone"` but it's not working.

Comment: I resolved problem with `remove`. Now you have new problem so create new question on new page - you will have more space for code, error mesage and other information

Answer (score 0):

**Try**:

```
roles = ""
for role in user.roles:
    if role.id == ctx.guild.id:
      continue
    roles += f" <@&{role.id}>"
```

Then maybe print the roles or send the roles in a channel (an embed is adviced cause it doesn't ping anyone, and looks prettier)